# How to set to pop-up notification in android application on a specific time slots even app is closed?

Tags: java, android, notifications

I want to set up notifications which are throwing out from my android application on specific time slots. lets say i want to pop out notification include "hello world" on 8.00 am, 12.00 pm, 6.00 pm . How to do that thing even my app is closed?

Comment: either your app is still 'invisibly' running, or you don't. an app that is shut down, can't send messages

Answer (score 2):

you can use background services or newer JobScheduler api
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html